# Dummy server for file uploading, OkHttp speed issue

Tags: android, api, server, multipartform-data, okhttp

I'm looking for an url, to which i can upload a file without tokens, authorization and so on. I can't quite find it by googling

Basically i need an url to which i can make `POST` request in multi part form data and get basic response, such as `OK`, i need this to calculate time needed for uploading

I need it because:

I'm developing Android App and using `OkHttp` for file uploading, code looks like this :

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    Multipart.Builder builder = new Multipart.Builder()
            .type(Multipart.Type.PARALLEL)
            .addPart(new Part.Builder()
                    .body(getSettings().getToken().getSessionId())
                    .contentDisposition("form-data; name=\"" + ParametersStrings.ACCESS_TOKEN + "\"")
                    .build())
            .addPart(new Part.Builder()
                    .body(KEY_JSON_RPC_VALUE)
                    .contentDisposition("form-data; name=\"" + KEY_JSON_RPC + "\"")
                    .build())
            .addPart(new Part.Builder()
                    .body(String.valueOf(sAutoIncrementId++))
                    .contentDisposition("form-data; name=\"" + KEY_ID + "\"")
                    .build())
            .addPart(new Part.Builder()
                    .body(file)
                    .contentDisposition("form-data; name=\"" + ParametersStrings.FILE + "\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"")
                    .build());
    Multipart multipart = builder.build();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    multipart.writeBodyTo(stream);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(multipart.getHeaders().get("Content-Type")), stream.toByteArray());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getUploadUri())
                .post(body).build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Time for uploading 11MB file to server takes 12 seconds within WIFI connection capable of 100MBit/S

I've also used pure HttpClient and time it takes almoust the same

I'm starting to guess it may something to do with server, so i'm trying to find another one, also, if you any suggestion to improve current code to speed it up, i'll gladly accept it.

**Question 1:** How can OkHttp and pure HttpClient on Android work so slow *(Time for uploading 11MB file to server takes 12 seconds within WIFI connection capable of 100MBit/S)* and how can i speed up my code written above

**Question 2:** Is there any dummy server, to which i can simply upload a multi part form data, and get simple response?

**Question 3:** If somebody familiar with uploading file by parts using `OkHttp` please help to figure it out

Comment: 12 seconds to upload an 11MB file seems about right - You do realize that a 100Mbit (100 megabits / sec) connection is only going to do about 10 MB (10 megabytes / sec) right ? (I hope I understand what you've written in the question right..). Check [here]http://henrycipollablog.com/2011/12/06/testing-multipartform-data-uploads-with-post-test-server/) for some info on a file upload test server you can use. I'm not entirely familiar with OkHttp, but your code looks about right to me.

Comment: @JonasCz, thx for rhe response. eventually friend of mine created server on which i was uploading, the speed was the same, but he said that there is a limitiation on uploading speed for the server, then i've tried to upload to youtube, speed was the same, so i reliazed thath server is fine, when i've started to dig dipper in the problem, i've found thath my customer was wrong. Basic thing that triggered this "issue" was that viber app is faster in multiple times, but after i've checked myself i've realized that this app just awfully compressing videos( from 11 mb to 0.7)